# Возврат массива строк С в python

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7, ctypes

Есть Си файл:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_STRING 4
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 1024

int func(const char **arr) {
    // char **arr = malloc(5 * sizeof(char*));
    arr[0] = "String 0";
    arr[1] = "String 1";
    arr[2] = "String 2";
    arr[3] = "String 3";
    arr[4] = "String 4";
    return 0;
}

int main () {
   // char **mas;
   // func(mas);
   // for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   //   printf("%s\n", mas[i]);
   // }
   return 0; 
}
```

Как получить результат работы функции func в python через ctypes?

Набросок py (2.7) файла

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL("d:\\project\\C\\untitled\\main.so")

# buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'0')
buf = (ctypes.c_char * 1024)()
# buf = (ctypes.c_char_p * 1024)()

res = lib.func(buf)

print(res)
print buf.value  # == 'D@�gM@�gV@�g_@�gh@�g'
```

Comment: А что не так? Вот это `(ctypes.c_char * 1024)()` выглядит подозрительно, а так похоже на правду

Comment: @gil9red, это из какого-то ответа на форуме. Проблема в том, что buf.value имеет значение 'D@�gM@�gV@�g_@�gh@�g'

Comment: А если так `buf= ((ctypes.c_char * 10) * 5)()`? `ctypes.c_char * 1024` это, я думаю, все таки одномерный массив

Comment: @gil9red, сделал итерации for x in buf, тогда x.value возвращает D@�gM@�gV@
�g_@�gh@�g и несколько пустых строк.

Comment: Сработало, осталось вам получить значения из этой матрицы. `.value` -- это для другого типа

Comment: @gil9red я обновил предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: @gil9red, использовал ((ctypes.c_char_p * 10) * 5)(), тогда buf[0][0] возвращает String0, buf[0][1] возвращает String1. Спасибо!

Comment: О, все-таки разобрались :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо

```
buf = (ctypes.c_char * 1024)()
```

Используйте:

```
buf = ((ctypes.c_char_p * 10) * 5)()
```

Comment: Небольшая опечатка. Нужно использовать  ctypes.c_char_p (указатель).

Comment: @ioprst, опечатался, вы правы :)